# Lista como referencia para completar otra lista pero intercalando y repitiendo los valores de la segunda lista, para formar una tercer lista

Tags: python-3.x, array, lista, pandas, numpy

Estoy desarrollando el siguiente script en Python utilizando los módulos ElementTree, Pandas y Numpy:

```
    def vectorize_values(num_signals, name, x_, y_):
        print(num_signals, name, x_, y_)
    
        # combined_dict = {}
        # for i, j in zip(x_, y_):
        #     combined_dict[i] = j
        # print(combined_dict)
    
        zipped = zip(name, x_, y_)
        # print(zipped)
    
        for i, (pos, val) in enumerate(zip(x_, y_)):
            pass
            # print(i, pos, val)
    
        for pos, val in zip(x_, y_):
            pass
            # print(pos, val)
    
        for i in y_:
            pass
            # print(i)
            for j in x_:
                pass
        # print(i)

        # for i in x_:
        #     print(i)
        # for j in y_:
        #     print(j)
        # if i > 0 & i != 1:
        #     zeros = np.zeros(i, dtype=int)
        #     print(zeros)

    def extract_signals(signals_df):
        num_signals = len(signals_df)
        names_list = [name for name in signals_df['Name'].unique()]
        # print(names_list)
    
        for pos, name in enumerate(names_list):
            # print(pos, name)
            # get data
            data = signals_df[signals_df["Name"] == name]["Value"]
            x_ = np.hstack([-1, data.index.values, len(signals_df) - 1])
            y_ = np.hstack([0, data.values, data.iloc[-1]])
            # Data to vectorize
            vectorize_values(num_signals, name, x_, y_)
    
    data_XML = [
        {"Name": signal.attrib["Name"],
         "Value": int(signal.attrib["Value"].split(' ')[0])
         } for signal in file_xml.findall(".//Signal")
    ]
    signals_df = pd.DataFrame(data_XML)
    
    extract_signals(signals_df)
```

Actualmente, la salida de esto está debajo, donde tengo la salida de una variable donde cuento el tamaño de la variable pandas, luego sigue otra variable que es otra cadena llamada nombre y luego están las 2 variables que son listas (x_ , y_):

```
    28 Status [-1 0  1 19 21 24 25 27] [0 4 4 1 1 4 4 4]
    28 HMI [-1 2 23 26 27] [0 2 1 2 2]
    28 AutoConfigO_Allst [-1 3 27] [0 1 1]
    28 AutoConfigO_Drvr [-1 4 27] [0 1 1]
    28 CurrTUBand [-1 5 10 27] [0 1 1 1]
    28 RUSource [-1 6 15 27] [0 0 0 0]
    28 RUReqstrPriority [-1 7 16 27] [0 7 7 7]
    28 RUReqstrSystem [-1 8 17 27] [0 0 0 0]
    28 RUResReqstStat [-1 9 18 27] [0 4 4 4]
    28 DSP [-1 11 14 27 27] [0 1 3 3 3]
    28 SetDSP [-1 12 13 27] [0 3 0 0]
    28 Delay [-1 20 22 27] [0 0 0 0]
```

Estas dos últimas variables (x_ y y_) que comento son las que quiero relacionar y debería de quedar como la salida que les comparto a más abajo.

Lo que quiero es tomar como referencia la variable x_ que son las posiciones de los valores de la variable y_ dentro del archivo xml ([visualizar archivo xml aqui](https://github.com/MarshRangel/Python/blob/develop/example_a_child4.xml)) y llenar primero de 0 los valores de enfrente o antes del primer valor de y_, pero en todas las salidas de la imagen compartida arriba; despues pretendo intercalar a partir de la columna 2 de la variable y_, llenarlos o completandolos con los valores que sean igual que la segunda columna hasta el tercer cambio, después tomar la tercer columna de la variable y_ y completarlo con los valores que sean igual que la tercer columna de y_ hasta el cuarto cambio, y asi sucesivamente. De hecho, **la salida que quiero lograr** lo muestro abajo:

```
     ['Status', [0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,  4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4]]
     ['HMI', [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1,  2, 2]]
     ['Allst', [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
     ['Drvr', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
     ['CurrTUBand', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
     ['RUSource', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
     ['RUReqstrPriority', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]]
     ['RUReqstrSystem', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
     ['RUResReqstStat', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
     ['DSP', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,  3, 3]]
     ['SetDSP', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
     ['Delay',[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Lo que he intentado es usar todos los for de la función vectorize_values() usando a su vez las funciones intgradas de Python zip o enumerate, pero no me sale lo que necesito. De antemano muchas gracias a quien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: En la imagen que muestras, la primera lista corresponde a `x_` y la según a `y_`?? Por otra parte recomiendo que cambies esas imágenes por texto

Comment: Hola Christian... no, la segunda salida es lo que quiero lograr. La primera es la salida de una variable donde contabilizo el tamaño de la cadena de caracteres, luego sigue otra variable que es otra cadena llamada nombre y despues están las 2 variables que son listas (x_ , y_), que quiero relacionar y quede como la segunda salida que es lo que espero lograr. Gracias!

Comment: Sigo sin entender bien qué quieres hacer con tu xml

Comment: El xml es solo para extraer la información, la extraigo con ayuda de la librería Pandas, una vez sacado el DataFrame de pandas, genero las variables x_ y y_ y esas son las que quiero formar en un solo vector, que es la segunda salida que se encuentra en mi pregunta.

Comment: no entendí el proceso para pasar de esto `[ 0  1 19 21 24 25 27] [4 4 1 1 4 4 4]` a esto `[0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,  4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4]`

Comment: Eso es precisamente, la razón de mi pregunta, porque no me sale.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127727/discussion-between-christian-and-marsh-rangel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que se entiende quieres llenar una lista de n elementos según las posiciones que tienes (en tu primera lista), en caso no exista tal posición en tu lista la quieres que el valor que tome sea el último en haber sido ingresado.

Viendo que tienes unos datos así:

```py
data = [["Status",[-1,0,1,19,21,24,25,27],[0,4,4,1,1,4,4,4]],
["HMI",[-1,2,23,26,27],[0,2,1,2,2]],
["AutoConfigO_Allst",[-1,3,27],[0,1,1]],
["AutoConfigO_Drvr",[-1,4,27],[0,1,1]],
["CurrTUBand",[-1,5,10,27],[0,1,1,1]],
["RUSource",[-1,6,15,27],[0,0,0,0]],
["RUReqstrPriority",[-1, 7, 16, 27],[0,7, 7, 7]],
["RUReqstrSystem",[-1,8,17,27],[0,0,0,0]],
["RUResReqstStat",[-1,9,18,27],[0,4,4,4]],
["DSP",[-1,11,14,27,27],[0,1,3,3,3]],
["SetDSP",[-1,12,13,27],[0,3,0,0]],
["Delay",[-1,20,22,27],[0,0,0,0]]]
```

Entonces deberíamos de recorrer cada uno de esos elementos. Para poder ir añadiendo estos elementos a una lista, debemos de tenerla previamente creada, para así solo ir añadiendo los valores según su posición, el resultado de la lista (con los datos insertados) lo almacenaremos en un diccionario. Para crear la lista inicial usaremos  numpy con `0` segun el valor máximo de la lista de posiciones.

Un problema es que tu lista de posiciones empiezan en `-1`, por lo que en realidad tu lista final no tendrá el numero máximo que se encuentre, sino tendremos que sumar `2.

```py
result = {} #aqui se almacena los resultados
for d in data:
    maxi = max(d[1]) #obtenemos el máximo del segundo elemento
    arr = np.zeros(maxi+2) #sumamos 2
    aft = 0 #se almacenará el elemento anterior
    for n in range(len(arr)): #recorremos en el rango del numpy array
        if n-1 in d[1]:  #verificamos si exite en la lista de posiciones
            i = d[1].index(n-1) 
            aft = d[2][i] #obtenemos el numero de la lista de valores
            arr[n] = aft #reemplazamos
        else: arr[n] = aft #reemplazamos por el ultimo que se agrego
    result[d[0]] = arr #agregamos al diccionario
```

Esto da como resultado en `result["Status"]`:

```
[0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Te agradezco mucho Christian :)